# Compile PostgreSQL with reverse endianness

Tags: postgresql, endianness

My old iMac G5 died recently. I had a PostgreSQL instance running there, and I kept backups. But when I went to restore them in my newer Macbook Pro, I realized that I couldn't do the restore due to byte endianness differences.

Is there any compile flags that I can pass to PostgreSQL's configure script to use a reversed endianness on Intel, allowing me to restore from backup, then do a SQL dump, and restore it on a default endianness instance?

Actually, I don't even know if I need to recompile PostgreSQL, perhaps there is some setting that someone can point me to to allow me to do the restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If your backups were made with pg_dump they'd be endian-independent, even if you used the binary format.

If you took a copy of the data directory (with the database shutdown, or using pg_start_backup()/pg_stop_backup()) you need to restore on a machine with the same endianness. You're probably best off importing it in a virtual machine with the same endianness somewhere, then dump from there with pg_dump and reload on your new machine.

If you took the backup from disk *without* shutting down PostgreSQL, the same basic thing holds, except you're also going to have to try to recover from a corrupt backup. That can be little work or hundreds of hours or more work depending on how much traffic you had on the database, and how lucky you are.